# Fixing the position in a scroll layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a scroll layout with a layout inflator to fill data from a database. Everything works fine then the screen opens, but when I scroll up, the items scroll past the beginning of where the margin is set at the beginning. I am doing this because I am using a static backgound image that I want to always stay in the same position. Is there a way for me to fix the scroll view?

Here is the XML for the main page.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backimage"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mylayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and this is the XML for each item I inflate to add to the scrollview

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/nocarpic" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@+id/TextView01" >

    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
         />

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/horizontalLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#8B0000"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want the scrolling content to clip 70dp below the top of the ScrollView, try removing the margin on the LinearLayout and instead setting `android:paddingTop="70dp"` on the ScrollView. ViewGroups clip child views to padding by default.